# Change side of the navigation pane in Outlook 2010

Tags: outlook, outlook-2010

I have a question regarding Microsoft Outlook. One person in my team said that it is possible to change side of the navigation pane (pane including favourites, inbox, etc.) from left to right side.

Is it really possible? I checked the documentation and didn't find the answer.

Thank you for any response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just received an official answer that it is not possible in Outlook 2010.